# Show Additional Variation Images In WooCommerce Variable Product Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

In this question, [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786855/enable-additional-variation-images-in-woocommerce-admin-variable-products/76790905) I'm able to select and add additional variation images from Woocommerce admin panel product variation section but then i'm trying to show this images on product page but i broke the entire slider system.

What did i do before asking this question?

1. Add "add-to-card" folder to woocommerce/single-product
2. Add "variable.php" file to "add-to-card" folder to add custom code to show variation images.
3. Lastly, i added code to variable.php. (you can see below)
4. Then i checked the product page but variation information like name, price, variation options (size and color) etc. are broken.

```
function display_variation_images() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $variation_ids = $product->get_children();

        if ( ! empty( $variation_ids ) ) {
            echo '<div class="variation-images">';
            foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
                $variation_image_ids = get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'variation_image', true );

                if ( is_array( $variation_image_ids ) && ! empty( $variation_image_ids ) ) {
                    foreach ( $variation_image_ids as $image_id ) {
                        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );
                        if ( $image_src ) {
                            echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image_src[0] ) . '" alt="Variation Image" class="variation-image" />';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'display_variation_images', 25 );
```